# Find all possible paths in a directed acyclic graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, path

I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with edges defined by the following vectors:

```
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 2     5
 3     5
 4     6
 5     7
```

where the left vector is the "from" node and the right vector is the "to" node.

I need a simple way in Matlab to extract all the paths starting at node 1 and terminating at a leaf node.

The output should be like this:

```
 1     1     1
 2     3     4
 5     5     6
 7     7
```

I made the following code to achieve this:

```
clc
clear all
filename = 'pre-paths.xlsx';
plans = xlsread(filename)

Paths = zeros(0,0);
PathNo = 1;
while(1)
    plan = plans;
    x = 1;
    j = 1;
    Activity = plan(PathNo, 1);
    Predecessor = plan(PathNo, 2);
    while(1)
        NewPath(j) = Activity;
        j = j + 1;
        NewPath(j) = Predecessor;
        j = j + 1;
        if(any(plan(:,1) == Predecessor) == 0)
            break;
        end
        ActivityIndex = find(plan(:,1) == Predecessor);
        Activity = plan(ActivityIndex(1), 1);
        Predecessor = plan(ActivityIndex(1), 2);
        x = x + 1;
        plan = plan(2:size(plan,1), :);
    end
    NewPath = unique(NewPath);
    for index = 1 : size(NewPath(:))
        Paths(index, PathNo) = NewPath(index);
    end
    PathNo = PathNo + 1;
    n = plans(PathNo, 1);
    anyn = any(plans(:,2) == n);
    if(anyn)
        break;
    end
end
for i = find(Paths == 0)
    Paths(i) = max(Paths(:)) + 1;
end
Paths
xlswrite('paths.xlsx',Paths);
```

But the problem is the code above works only on the test case I mentioned earlier. When I use it on different vectors the output resulted is wrong.

I'm not very strong in MATLAB and not a professional coder. Can someone help me understand a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by paths?

Comment: I mean that I want to create paths by determining the successor and predecessor from the two vectors above, the predecessor represented in first vector and successor is represented in second vector.

Comment: It's ok if it's NaN. I only need is just make a list of paths that determines who's previous and who's next from these two vectors. for instance, Number 1 in first vector represents predecessor and number 2 in second vector represents the sucessor, number 2 in first vector in 4th row represents predecessor, number 5 in second vector in 4th row represents sucessor. So, the result is 1 -> 2 -> 5 and so on. Just check out the output I posted above and you will know what I mean

Comment: Not all the time the elements are in ascending order.
I used about size 167 vector and it didn't work for me. Do you want to posted here?

Comment: If you asking for a sample of elements that wan't work for me, then here it is:
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 11
11 12
12 13
13 14
14 15
15 16
16 17
17 18
18 19
19 20
20 21
21 22
22 23
23 24
24 25
25 26
26 27
27 28
28 29
29 30
30 31

Comment: This is the rest of it:
20 32
32 33
33 34
34 35
35 36
36 37
37 38
38 39
39 40
20 41
41 42
42 43
43 44
31 45
45 46
46 47
47 48
48 49
49 50
50 51
51 52
52 53
40 54
44 54
54 55
55 56
56 57
57 58
58 59
53 60
60 61
61 62
62 63
63 64
64 65
65 66
66 67
67 68
68 69
69 70
59 70
70 71

Comment: consider the first element is in first vector and second element in second vector ans so on..

Comment: You're trying to find all of the paths in a depth-first traversal of your graph. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a function in MATLAB to do this.